# send notification after adding/updating/deleting user role in wso2is 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2IS 5.10.0 so I need to send notification email after adding,updating or deleting user role of any user. For that I refer this wso2 document [1](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-email-sending/) and [2](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/enabling-notifications-for-user-operations/#enabling-notifications-for-user-operations) but it is not working as expected. Is there any workaround to resolve this ?

Comment: Could you provide more information on how you have configured, the scenarios you tried, and what error you got?

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned in this [document](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-email-sending/), first you need to configure output event adapter to configure the email account that need to be used to send email notifications
2. Then you need to subscribe the email sender module for the user operation events as mentioned in this [document](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/enabling-notifications-for-user-operations/#enabling-notifications-for-user-operations).

For example, to configure email notification for after adding,updating or deleting user role,
A sample configuration in identity-event.properties file will look like below:

```
module.name.2=emailSend
emailSend.subscription.1=TRIGGER_NOTIFICATION
emailSend.subscription.2=POST_ADD_ROLE
emailSend.subscription.3=POST_UPDATE_ROLE
emailSend.subscription.4=POST_DELETE_ROLE
```

But adding this configuration directly into the **identity-event.properties will be overidden** due to new config model introduced with IS5.9.0.

So you have to add the following config **directly into deployment.toml** file.

```
  [identity_mgt.events.schemes.emailSend]
subscriptions = [
       "TRIGGER_NOTIFICATION",
       "POST_ADD_ROLE",
       "POST_UPDATE_ROLE",
       "POST_DELETE_ROLE"
     ]

[identity_mgt.events.schemes.emailSend.properties]
'subscription.POST_ADD_ROLE.template' = "testDelete"
```

You can add properties here for each subscription under properties.

You can refer to this identity-event.properties.j2 file for further reference. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/master/features/identity-event/org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.server.feature/resources/identity-event.properties.j2

You can refer this [blog](https://medium.com/@isurakarunaratne/wso2-identity-server-eventing-framework-32505bcc1600) for further information.